# Development frameworks for 2D game?

Tags: cross-platform, pygame, pyglet

I wanted to start working on a simple game concept I have, just as a side project/hobby/learning experience.

Pygames or Pyglet came immediately to mind, but it looks like they aren't being actively developed.  Or perhaps they are, but extreeemely slowly.

I want a high-level programming language, multi-OS support, 2D focus (or suitable for 2D stuff, anyway), and active development.  What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Pygame and think it is a great option.  The community is fairly active, I see a new or updated project posted about every other day on Pygame's homepage.

Another good option would be the Love2d framework, which you can find here: http://love2d.org/.  Love2d uses the language Lua, which is a high level, beginner-friendly language like Python.

Comment: Love2d has pretty much what I want, except for a 1.0 release.  Still, it's fast and has just the right amount of do-it-yourselfness/baked in awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame and Pyglet are indeed excellent choices.  If the level of activity concerns you, just take a look at the [Google Code page](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/) for Pyglet, seems it's fairly active to me.

Comment: 1.14 is from December 2009.  That's forever ago.  It's production ready and awesome still?  For real?

Comment: They may not make numbered releases all too frequently but like I said there's constantly activity in the repo for Pyglet.  As for "production ready and awesome" I'd say both Pygame and Pyglet are perfectly viable.  When it comes to which is better I think that's all personal preference and which you feel you'll benefit most from.

Answer (score 0):

The PopCap (a.k.a. SexyApp) engine was a popular choice in the past. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/popcapframework/

For real-world example, check out the acclaimed indie game World of Goo, which is using it. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Goo

If python API is preferred, there seems to be an effort to provide one here: 
http://www.farbs.org/pycap.html

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer more actively developed engine (less documentation, but more up-to-date approaches), check out the Monacle Engine: 
http://monoclepowered.org/

Answer (score 0):

If want to get your hands dirty and take a more Do-It-Yourself approach, projects like
SDL, SFML and Allegro may provide a good foundation for a cross-platform 2D engine.

Another, more recent project that provides a very useful set of 2D primitives is the Clutter framework: 
http://www.clutter-project.org/

Add a sound library like FMOD or BASS and physics engine like Box2D or Chipmunk and you may build pretty much everything.